# which sorting algorithm for linked list?

Tags: algorithm, sorting, linked-list, singly-linked-list, doubly-linked-list

Which sorting algorithm fits best for singly linked lists and double linked lists that have less than 20 items or almost sorted list? I try to understand which sorting algorithms fit for small lists I understand for arrays but do not understand how it is for linked lists.

Comment: Why use a linked list? This data structure is not suitable for most sorting algorithms.

Comment: i have to implement the "best" sorting algorithm for singly linked list and double therefore i wonder which one is most suitable for a small linked list because i can not find so much information about it

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [on topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) apply here.  Among other things, you haven't defined "best" -- and some of that definition might depend on the node structure and the implementation environment.

Answer (score 2):

Insertion sort works quite fast for **nearly sorted** arrays and will be a good option for a doubly linked list too. For **small sized inputs**, it doesn't really matter which algorithm you prefer since all of them will end up in constant time. Note however, advanced algorithms are a bit overkill if there are like 10-20 elements to be sorted. The overhead is big.

In linked lists, Merge sort can be performed in place, not using extra memory, since it's possible to merge nodes in a linked list in O(1) time without the use of an extra array. Quicksort however is worse. It uses lots of indexing, which is something linked structures are bad at.

Choosing a simple algorithm, Selection sort is usually never the best choice since it always performs in O(N^2) time. Bubble sort and Insertion sort have best case O(N) and the same worst case as Selection sort.

Insertion sort on the other hand does not perform well on a singly linked list since we cannot move backwards, only forward. Bubble sort works fine. For a doubly linked list, both performs well.

Comment: Well, you need to mention the fact that insertion sort for a singly linked list is a horrible choice because we have no possible to go back in such list. N log N operations works just fine with a linked list. HOWEVER now that we have like 20 elements, it works fine with a simple algorithm. Bubble, selection for singly linked. And the same two plus insertion for a doubly linked

Comment: I said it is not a good idea but I guess I should have point that out more strongly so I updated my answer. For some reason, I eliminated selection sort last night but I realized it is easy to use by using a second pointer to the current index location, thanks for pointing that out. I am still not very sure about how well quicksort or merge sort will perform though. Anyway, I updated my solution by using your comment, thanks.

Comment: It's better but still not fully correct. There's absolutely a point in choosing Bubble and Insertion over Selection since they have O(N) best case and selection always performs O(N^2). Selection sort will probably never be the best algorithm to choose.